# R adding values to vector in for loop

Tags: r

I'm working in R & using a for loop to iterate through my data:

```
pos = c(1256:1301,6542:6598)
sd_all = null


for (i in pos){
    nameA = paste("A", i, sep = "_")
    nameC = paste("C", i, sep = "_")
    resA = assign(nameA, unlist(lapply(files, function(x) x$percentageA[x$position==i])))
    resC = assign(nameC, unlist(lapply(files, function(x) x$percentageC[x$position==i])))
    sd_A = sd(resA)
    sd_C = sd(resC)
    sd_all = ?
}
```

now I want to generate a vector called 'sd_all' that contains the standard deviations of resA & resC. I cannot just do 'sd_all = c(sd(resA), sd(resC))', because then I only use one value in 'pos'. I want to do it for all values in 'pos' off course.

Comment: How do you want `sd_all` to look? Since each iteration of the loop would be inserting 2 values into `sd_all`, maybe it should be a list, or a data.frame?

Comment: @rosscova: I will use 'sd_all' later as a column in an already existing data.frame.

Comment: Well there are 2 ways to do that, you could add `sd_A` and `sd_B` to that data.frame as separate columns (since there are 2 values per iteration, so one value per column per row of your data.frame), or you could make it a list column with 2 values per "cell".

Comment: @rosscova: but for now I just want it to be a vector with the values like this: sd_A for pos 1256, sd_C for pos 1256, sd_A for pos 1257, sd_C for 1257, ...

Comment: OK, it seems like a `list` is probably what your after. I've added an answer with a method on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'd be best served with `sd_all` as a list object. That way you can insert each of your 2 values ( `sd(resA)` and `sd(resC)` ).

Initialising a list is simple (this would replace the second line of your code):

```
sd_all <- list()
```

Then you can insert both the values you want to into a single list element like so (this would replace the last line in your `for` loop):

```
sd_all[[ i ]] <- c( sd( resA ), sd( resC ) )
```

After your loop, you can then insert this list as a column in a data.frame if that's what you'd like to do.